# Permission check event (or log) for Android

Tags: android, android-event, android-permissions, android-broadcast

I understand that when you install an android app you need to accept the permissions requested by the app. When you run the app, when it comes to the point that app really about to use that permission and perform a task, the android system has to check again "whether this app is allowed to perform this task?". I need to perform some task (log the event) at this moment. How can I do this?

There is a catch. I want to identify these instances (moments) for other running apps (not for my app)

(Ex: I want to know when DropBox app is about to access the internet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to perform some task (log the event) at this moment.  How can I do this?

You can download the Android source code, modify it to incorporate your desired security flaw, compile the results into a ROM mod, and install that ROM mod on your own device.

This is not possible via the Android SDK.

> There is a catch. I want to identify these instances (moments) for other running apps (not for my app) (Ex: I want to know when DropBox app is about to access the internet.)

You are welcome to install and use a firewall package on your rooted Android device and perhaps hook something up that way, for this specific scenario. In general, what you seek is not possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.